# Why docker still connect or pull from remote registry when images are already present locally?

Tags: docker

Now I have the image `gcr.io/google_containers/pause-amd64:3.0` locally, but when I exec `docker pull gcr.io/google_containers/pause-amd64:3.0`, it report `Error response from daemon: Get https://gcr.io/v1/_ping: dial tcp 108.177.125.82:443: i/o timeout`. I'm confused why docker still connect or pull from remote registry when images are already present locally? Does it connect to the remote registry to downlaod and check some metadata? Am I right? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you execute `docker pull image_name:sometag`, you explicitly instruct docker daemon to pull the requested image/tag.

Quoting `docker pull` description from [official documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/pull/):

> Pull an image or a repository from a registry

So it is completely natural for docker when you execute a `docker pull` to access the remote registry to pull the image.

If the image  **is present locally**, you will only get updates for it, else docker will fetch it in order to be available in your local repository.

> I'm confused why docker still connect or pull from remote registry when images are already present locally?

`docker run` works like this. When an image **is not present** locally will try to download from a registry else will just start a container from the already fetched image.

Comment: Thanks@leopal. Your answer has cleared up my confusion.